# How to use hooks in Stylus?

Tags: less, hook, stylus

I would like to make hooking in Stylus by using mixin like it does in LESS. It seems like Stylus can't make @extend .className before .className is defined, but LESS does.

For example. By LESS logic It may look like

```
    .uk-button {
        display: inline-block;
        border 1px solid #00f;
    }

    .hook-button() {}

    .hook-button() {
        border 1px solid #00a;
    }
```

but by Stylus logic It must be

```
hook-button()    
  .hook-button
    {block}

+hook-button()
  border 1px solid #00f

.uk-button
  display inline-block
  border 1px solid #00a
  @extend .hook-button
```

Is there any way to place hook after @extend in Stylus?

**upd**: The main problem is that override goes before wanted class. You could try online [LESS](http://less2css.org/) and  [Stylus](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html).

Comment: Well, Stylus `@extend` is not a mixin but the same thing as Less `:extend` (which you can't use for "hooks" too of course)... Look at Stylus [mixins](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/mixins.html).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thank you for comment and sorry for miss understanding. The main problem is that override goes before wanted class. You could try [online Stylus](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html)

Comment: Ah, I see now. Hmm, I'm not really a Stylus expert but I'm afraid it does not support lazy-evaluation (i.e. "use before definition") like Less does. Though maybe you could try to trick it by hiding the `@extend` in another mixin defined before `.uk-button`...

Comment: @seven-phases-max yeah, you're right. There's no way to do that. Thank you for your help!